# duplicity suddenly fails with Python tuple error

Tags: duplicity

I have been using duplicity in a cron job for a year now, has worked just fine. Starting from last week I got the following message:

```
Ausdruckbasierte Dateiliste wird gelesen /home/mu/.config/exclude-b2.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1637, in <module>
    if "Forced assertion for testing" in util.uexc(e):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 82, in uexc
    return ufn(m)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 63, in ufn
    return filename.decode(globals.fsencoding, 'replace')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The last upgrade to the `duplicity` package on my Fedora 30 system has been 2019-05-09, I am running version 0.7.19. The backup goes to Backblaze B2.

Is there some way that I can get this pinned down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another instance where an interrupted backup leaves duplicity in a state where it cannot recover. I have deleted the partial files from the last incremental backup and now it works again.

Comment: How do you recognize the "partial files from the last incremental backup". In my duplicity folder I have a folder `duplicity-full.20190520T221318Z.vol1.difftar` from "Saturday" (with an empty snapshot directory inside), `duplicity-new-signatures.20191003T172053Z.to.20191004T101428Z.sigtar.gz`, `duplicity-inc.20191003T172053Z.to.20191004T101428Z.vol1.difftar.gz`, and `duplicity-inc.20191003T172053Z.to.20191004T101428Z.manifest` from "Friday" and a lot more files from before. Are you suggesting to delete the folder (from "Saturday") or all the files from "Friday"?

Comment: This worked for me, out of desperation I deleted the last basically empty directory `duplicity-full.20190520T221318Z.vol1.difftar` and it worked. Saved my life, I wish I had more credit to give a larger bounty. I made the backup with Fedora 30 (Deja dup) and tried to restore with duplicity 0.7.18.2 in Ubuntu 19.04, and also with Fedora 30.

Comment: I think I just deleted all the files which contained the most recent date. No need for a bounty, I'm very happy to hear that it helped you! 

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source downloadable from [gnu](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), it seems it is trying to handle an exception, and getting an exception whilst doing so, which is not helpful.  I think you are in the very last lines of `/usr/bin/duplicity`:

```py
except Exception as e:
    util.release_lockfile()
    if "Forced assertion for testing" in util.uexc(e):
        log.FatalError(u"%s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)),
                       log.ErrorCode.exception,
                       e.__class__.__name__)
    else:
        # Traceback and that mess
        log.FatalError(util.exception_traceback(),
                       log.ErrorCode.exception,
                       e.__class__.__name__)
```

It calls `util.uexc(e)` to look for some text that is only used during testing (apparently), and this routine is failing for some reason. You can try just changing the `if` to start `if False and` instead to bypass this test and see if you then get the real cause of the exception logged.
You might also try changing to the C locale temporarily to see if that changes anything.